# How to make a JQuery Notification Pop-Up (like Toast) appears outside the App Script sandbox modal?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on an add-ons for the new Google Spreadsheet and I have a process taking a few seconds and I would like to show the user a notification popup. But I would like it to appear outside the modal sandbox that google create (see picture below) - meaning I would like the google sandbox model not to be visible at all - only my pop-up.

I am not sure how to do it with the HTMLServices.

I know it's feasible I saw it on the Solve360 CRM Add-Ons (new Google Spreadsheet). They have a hourglass pop-up like a toast message but custom.

This is my code for a test in a new google spreadsheet:

```
function test_modal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('toastr').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  ss.show(html);  
}
```

And the HTML file used:

I am using the JQuery Notification called toastr.js (but could be any).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    toastr.warning('This is a test warning toast pop-up')
  });
</script>
```

[image: JQuery Popup]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpeadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast()` for a notification in the bottom right corner.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast%28String%29

Example from documentation:

```
// Show a popup with the message "Task started".
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Task started');
```

Any jQuery solutions won't work because they create `<div>`s within the sandbox.

Comment: I know about Toast and it's not what I need. Maybe there is another thing that can do it? As mentioned, you can see a working example with the Add-Ons of Solve360 CRM (search CRM in the Get Add-Ons, install it and see for yourself) which has exactly what looks like a JQuery notification popup. So somebody found a way to do it.

Comment: The black thing with a refreshing icon + text? I think that' s just Google's way of showing a script is running.